# CKeditor 4 replace config param for each field

Tags: ckeditor

I got 3 textarea on page. 
It's conected with CKeditor. also got CKeditor plugin on it.

I wish to have different characters count for each field.
Now I give it in config for all of them:

```
CKEDITOR.config.wordcount.maxCharCount=30;
```

to sum up:
how I change config value for one field in ck'editor

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the tag MaxLength on each individual control.

```
<cke:CKEditorControl ID="ckeText" Toolbar="" AutoGrowOnStartup="true" MaxLength="5" runat="server" />
```

You can also find all of that information on their documentation website [docs.ckeditor.com](http://docs.ckeditor.com/)

Comment: nope...just becouse..when I write something, CKeditor adds some html tags. they count in to the maxlenght

Comment: oh,.. sorry about that, that sounds like a bug, but I'll bet it's a feature. In my experience the purpose for max length is to not get an error when trying to shove it into a char db field. Does it have to be client side? As an alternative solution I would increase the max size to include the paragraph tag, then remove it on the back end.

If that doesn't make sense for you application, I would write a custom script to handle the restriction.